# Folding over references inside a match results in a lifetime error

Tags: functional-programming, rust, lifetime, borrowing

I want to build a string `s` by iterating over a vector of simple structs, appending different strings to `acc` depending on the struct.

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Point(Option<i32>, Option<i32>);

impl Point {

    fn get_first(&self) -> Option<i32> {
        self.0
    }

}

fn main() {

    let mut vec = vec![Point(None, None); 10];
    vec[5] = Point(Some(1), Some(1));


    let s: String = vec.iter().fold(
        String::new(),
        |acc, &ref e| acc + match e.get_first() {
            None => "",
            Some(ref content) => &content.to_string()
        }
    );

    println!("{}", s);

}
```

Running this code results in the following error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
            Some(ref content) => &content.to_string()
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: reference must be valid for the expression at 21:22...
        |acc, &ref e| acc + match e.get_first() {
                      ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the expression at 23:33
            Some(ref content) => &content.to_string()
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The problem is that the lifetime of the `&str` I create seems to end immediately. However, if `to_string()` would have returned a `&str` in the first place, the compiler would not have complained. Then, what is the difference?

How can I make the compiler understand that I want the string references to live as long as I am constructing `s`?

Comment: (FYI: Moving `acc +` to each branch works: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=95adc6ff8736d21b941a8a89ef67f582&version=stable&backtrace=0.)

Comment: Yes, it does. Must have been the last thing I didn't try before making this post. why though?

Comment: It's because the lifetime of acc is greater than the match statement. A new string built in match only lives within its block.

Comment: Of course. thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference between the result of your branches:

- `""` is of type `&'static str`
- `content` is of type `i32`, so you are converting it to a `String` and then from that to a `&str`... but this `&str` has the same lifetime as the `String` returned by `to_string`, which dies too early

A quick work-around, as mentioned by @Dogbert, is to move `acc +` inside the branches:

```
let s: String = vec.iter().fold(
    String::new(),
    |acc, &ref e| match e.get_first() {
        None => acc,
        Some(ref content) => acc + &content.to_string(),
    }
);
```

However, it's a bit wasteful, because every time we have an integer, we are allocating a `String` (via `to_string`) just to immediately discard it.

A better solution is to use the `write!` macro instead, which just appends to the original string buffer. This means there are no wasted allocations.

```
use std::fmt::Write;

let s = vec.iter().fold(
    String::new(),
    |mut acc, &ref e| {
        if let Some(ref content) = e.get_first() {
            write!(&mut acc, "{}", content).expect("Should have been able to format!");
        }
        acc
    }
);
```

It's maybe a bit more complicated, notably because formatting adds in error handling, but is more efficient as it only uses a single buffer.

Comment: You can use `String` with the `write!()` macro by using `std::fmt::Write` instead. This makes the code shorter. I'd also prefer `if let Some(ref content) = e.get_first() { write!(...); } acc` to avoid "returning" `acc` twice..

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: Much better!

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple solutions to your problem. But first some explanations:

> If `to_string()` would have returned a `&str` in the first place, the compiler would not have complained. Then, what is the difference?

Suppose there is a method `to_str()` that returns a `&str`. What would the signature look like?

```
fn to_str(&self) -> &str {}
```

To better understand the issue, lets add explicit lifetimes (that are not necessary thanks to lifetime elision):

```
fn to_str<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str {}
```

It becomes clear that the returned `&str` lives as long as the receiver of the method (`self`). This would be OK since the receiver lives long enough for your `acc + ...` operation. In your case however, the `.to_string()` call creates a new object the only lives in the second match arm. After the arm's body is left, it will be destroyed. Therefore you can't pass a reference to it to the outer scope (in which `acc + ...` takes place).

---

So *one* possible **solution** looks like this:

```
let s = vec.iter().fold(
    String::new(), 
    |acc, e| {
        acc + &e.get_first()
                .map(|f| f.to_string())
                .unwrap_or(String::new())
    }
);
```

It's not optimal, but luckily your default value is an empty string and the owned version of an empty string (`String::new()`) does not require any heap allocations, so there is no performance penalty.

However, we are still allocating once per integer. For a more efficient solution, see [Matthieu M.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39232212/2408867).